# Deploy Google app script to run without user authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a google app script for a google sheet for one of my classes. I've put a link on my website, but it forces my students to log in to google (or sign up for an account). How can I prevent this from happening so that they can just use the app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer depends on the nature of your script, which you haven't specified. As you mention "a link on [your] website", it sounds like you've published the script as a web app.

If that's the case, then just ensure that you've set the script to (a) run as you and (b) have open access. See the screenshot of the Publish dialog, below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @02fentym - If you have a GAFE (Google Apps for education) account you will have more options (users in your domain...) but Mogsdad's answers remains the only possible way to allow "not logged in" users to use the app.

Comment: Thanks guys...I actually had that setting on, but for some reason I think I was publishing another version of the app; weird! I messed with the settings a bit and it seems to be working now. Thanks :)

Comment: i'm using "execute the app as" me, and who has access to app: anyone, but it's still requiring login when i use incognito window, any ideas?

Comment: hi, how can i do this with desktop app?