# How to execute UrlFetchApp.fetch() without displaying the OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, urlfetch

I am creating an app with Google Apps Script.

This app uses UrlFetchApp.fetch(), so the user who runs the app for the first time will see the OAuth consent screen.

By the way, the scope required by the app is as follows.
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`

Is there a solution to hide the consent screen in order to reduce user interaction?

Comment: Please add the details of how you set up the web app deployment and briefly explain why you set up it that way.

Comment: I want to link it with Google Chat, so I select Publish > Deploy from Manifest in the code edit screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want and it doesn't matter if the user will execute your web app using your credentials, then choose **Me** under **Execute as** so they won't need to interact with the OAuth screen.

#### Reference:

- [Deploy Google app script to run without user authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25855662/14606045)

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using the method you taught me.
Is it possible to hide the OAuth screen when I select Publish > Deploy from Manifest in the code edit screen?

Comment: Quoting from documentation: `Certain OAuth scopes are sensitive because they allow access to Google User Data. If your script project uses scopes that allow access to user data, the project must go through OAuth client verification before you can publish it publicly as a web app or add-on.` So with that in mind, having your script access to user data requires OAuth. I don't think we can hide/bypass OAuth in that regard. Reference: [OAuth Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#oauth_verification)

Comment: Hi @noobchan, if we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)