# Google Apps Script function is not triggered when cell is edited

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a function that uploads the image to Google Drive through Google Sheets and creates its link in Google Sheets Cell. Here is the code snippet:

```
function upload(obj) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById("###").createFile(obj.upload);
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var File_name = file.getName()
  var value = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + File_name + '")'
  
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.getRange("B2").setFormula(value)
  
  return {
    fileId: file.getId(),
    mimeType: file.getMimeType(),
    fileName: file.getName(),
  };
}

function onChecked(e) {
 if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'I1' && e.value === 'TRUE') {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('upload');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
  }
}
```

I have set up onEdit trigger on `onChecked(e)` function that whenever checkbox in **cell I1** is checked this function will be triggered to upload image in Google Drive. The purpose of setting this as on Edit trigger is that:

> Users do not need to authorize the script/scopes as they are not
> technical. So I authorized the scopes of the script during trigger
> installation.

It works fine for me but when any other user except me checks this checkbox, it does not upload the image. It means `upload` function is not executed by any other user. Here is `upload.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form> <!-- Modified -->
    <div id="progress" ></div>
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="file">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data(this.parentNode)" >
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </form>
  <script>
    function form_data(obj){ // Modified
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).upload(obj);
    };
    function closeIt(e){ // Modified
      console.log(e);
      google.script.host.close();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To summarize the issue, this function works fine for me but when other users try to run it, it only executes `onChecked` function, but the `upload()` function does not run.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you want to make users upload the user's file to your folder on your Google Drive? Or, do you want to make users upload the user's file to the user's folder on the user's Google Drive? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: yes, I want to make users upload the users' files to my folder on my Google Drive.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `However, my main goal is that users do not need to authorize the script.`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice about it from your question. In that case, my answer was not suitable for your actual expected result. So, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. And, I think that in your situation, how about uploading the file using the Web Apps? I think that it might be suitable for your actual expected situation.

Comment: I apologize I have modified my question and mentioned scopes, the reason I am not using Webapp is that the user has to do it from the sheet because the user adds other relevant information as well which is not possible with Webapp.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your actual expected result, you want to achieve your goal without both authorizing the scopes by users and using Web Apps. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: About `yes, you are right`, thank you for replying. When I could find the method for achieving your goal without both authorizing the scopes by users and using Web Apps, I would like to post it as an answer. By the way, can you update your question to avoid confusing your actual question?

Comment: By the way, can you update your question to avoid confusing your actual question? In your current question, it seems that the explanation about Web Apps is not mentioned.

Comment: Security wise, unfortunately, it it possible to do this without authorization, same as this post: [Upload file to my google drive from anyone using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903378/upload-file-to-my-google-drive-from-anyone-using-javascript/23904870#23904870) unless you will make it as `web app` just like in this SO post: [Deploy Google app script to run without user authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854660/deploy-google-app-script-to-run-without-user-authorization)

Comment: Also looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth), the scope that you want is in `restricted` usage means, it needs authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to make users upload a file to the folder on your Google Drive using your showing script.
- In your script, the function `onChecked` has already been installed as the OnEdit trigger.
- You want to achieve your goal without both authorizing scopes by the user and using Web Apps.

#### Modification points:

- In your situation, the following flow is required to be done.

  1. It seems that in the current stage, in your current script, in order to use `google.script.run`, the user is required to authorize the scopes of the script.
  2. In order to achieve your goal, both the upload of the file and the update of the Spreadsheet are required to be done on the dialog.
  3. In order to achieve this, at least, 2 scopes of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui` are required to be used.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### 1. Update `appsscript.json`

Please update your `appsscript.json` as follows.

```json
{
  "timeZone": "###", <--- this is your timezone.
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "drive"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ]
}
```

- By this, 2 scopes are used and Drive API and Sheets API are enabled.

#### 2. Modified script

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet.

##### Google Apps Script side:

**Please reinstall `onChecked` as the OnEdit trigger again.** By this, 2 scopes are authorized.

```js
function onChecked(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'I1' && e.value === 'TRUE') {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('upload');
    html.token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    html.spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

    html.folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID.

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(), 'Upload File');
  }
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side:

Please set your folder ID and Spreadsheet ID to `folderId` and `spreadsheetId`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js/resumableupload_js.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="upload" id="file">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data(this.parentNode)" >
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    </form>
    <div id="progress"></div>

    <script>
      function form_data(obj) {
        const file = obj.upload.files[0];
        if (file.name != "") {
          let fr = new FileReader();
          fr.fileName = file.name;
          fr.fileSize = file.size;
          fr.fileType = file.type;
          fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          fr.onload = resumableUpload;
        }
      }

      function resumableUpload(e) {
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "Initializing.";
        const f = e.target;
        const resource = {
          fileName: f.fileName,
          fileSize: f.fileSize,
          fileType: f.fileType,
          fileBuffer: f.result,
          accessToken: "<?!= token ?>",
          folderId: "<?!= folderId ?>",
        };
        const ru = new ResumableUploadToGoogleDrive();
        ru.Do(resource, function (res, err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          console.log(res);
          let msg = "";
          if (res.status == "Uploading") {
            msg = Math.round((res.progressNumber.current / res.progressNumber.end) * 100) + "%";
          } else {
            msg = res.status;
          }
          document.getElementById("progress").innerText = msg;
          if (res.result) {
            const fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + res.result.id + "/view?usp=drivesdk";
            const formula = `=hyperlink("${fileUrl}";"${f.fileName}")`;
            const url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<?!= spreadsheetId ?>/values/B2?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";
            fetch(url, {
              method: "PUT",
              headers: {
                authorization: "Bearer " + resource.accessToken,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({values: [[formula]]})
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data);
              google.script.host.close();
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
          }
        });
      }
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- In this case, I used [my Javascript library](https://github.com/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js) for uploading the file. Because I'm not sure about the file size of your situation.

#### 3. Testing

When you check the checkbox of "I1", the dialog is opened. And, please upload a file. By this, the file is put into the folder to `folderId`, and the file URL is put into "B2".

#### Note:

- If you don't want to use your access token, I think that the service account can be also used. But, at that time, please modify the above script.
- When I tested this script, I confirmed that the user who is not the owner of Spreadsheet uploads a file, the file could be correctly uploaded and the file URL is put into "B2".
- In this case, the user cannot open the uploaded file because the owner of the file is not the user. But, if the folder of `folderId` is shared with the user, the user can open the file.

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, my main goal is that users do not need to authorize the script. That's why I set it up as on Edit trigger so that users can run the script on my behalf, mostly my users have no idea how to authorize scripts or scopes.

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. About `However, my main goal is that users do not need to authorize the script.`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice about it from your question. In that case, my answer was not suitable for your actual expected result. So, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. And, I think that in your situation, how about uploading the file using the Web Apps? I think that it might be suitable for your actual expected situation.

Comment: @EagleEye In order to achieve your goal, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. In this answer, the user can upload a file without both authorizing the scopes and using the Web Apps.

Comment: can we please pass the sheet id and folder id from the google apps script side to html side instead of doing it manually? This code is heavily on html side, Can we shift it to apps script side, sorry if is out of scope.

Comment: ok, I will work on it, thank you for your answer

Comment: @EagleEye About `can we please pass the sheet id and folder id from the google apps script side to html side instead of doing it manually?`, I think that this might be able to be achieved. Please wait for it.

Comment: @EagleEye Now, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. In this case, the folder ID and the spreadsheet ID are given from Google Apps Script to Javascript. Please set your folder ID. And the spreadsheet ID of the active Spreadsheet is used.